# "Csc.exe" could not be run. Access is denied (MSB6003)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, package, access-denied, csc

I just downloaded and installed Xamarin and selected the ASP.NET MVC template. I haven't touched anything. When I build the solution I get the following error:

Could not add packages.
"The specified task executable "Csc.exe" could not be run. Access is denied (MSB6003)".

This is at the end of messages displayed on the Package Console:

Added file 'packages.config'.
An exception was thrown while dispatching a method call in the UI thread.

I'm running Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio Community 2015.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running visual studio as administrator?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?